# @nodert-win10-c\windows.ui.notifications\build\Release\binding.node is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am have installed windows.ui.notifications and nodert-win10-au/windows.ui.notifications, But when tiring to compile the app, am getting `@nodert-win10-c\windows.ui.notifications\build\Release\binding.node is not a valid Win32 application[![enter image description here][1]][1]`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm0XD.png)

Comment: What are you compiling? What does this have to do with React and Electron?

Comment: Also, the error is most likely a result of something trying to execute a DLL, V8 (engine used by Node.js) code, or JS code as an exectuable.

Comment: Just i am compiling the app `npm run dev` .

Comment: And what's the build script? `package.json` defines that, what's in there?

Comment: `npm run build && electron-builder -w -c.extraMetadata.main=build/electron.js`, this is build script

Development : `"dev": "concurrently \"npm start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\""`

Comment: Can you run `npm run build` and run `npm run dev` again?

Comment: Yes i did again. But got same error

Comment: I don't have any idea, then. Try to follow the setup guide (if provided) for the Node bindings of `Windows.Ui.Notifications`